# Importing services to jBPM 6.0

Tags: jbpm

I'm doing a project with jBPM. We decided to migrate to the 6.0 version from 5.3.

In the 5.3 version Eclipse had an option to import custom services to the modeler. Now something has changed, my own version of the server that was serving work items does not work. The same is with an repo from one of the guys from redhat:
`http://people.redhat.com/kverlaen/repository/`

So how this should be done now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo address changed and it works:

`http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/repository/`